# Install pip3 package using ansible instead of pip2

Tags: django, vagrant, pip, ansible

I am trying to setup a Django project in `vagrant` using `ansible`. I have used the following code for installing the `pip packages`:

```
- name: Setup Virtualenv
  pip: virtualenv={{ virtualenv_path }} virtualenv_python=python3 requirements={{ virtualenv_path }}/requirements.txt
```

I need to use `python3` for the django project and even though I have explicitly mentioned to use python3, it is `installing the pip packages via pip2`. I have ensured that python3 is installed on the virtual machine.

Please, help me install the packages via pip3.

Comment: is python3 installed on the VM ?

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Yes, it installed on the VM.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri Please suggest something.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to use `executable` option. Excerpt from `pip` module [doc](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/pip_module.html):

> `executable` (added in 1.3)
>
> The explicit executable or a pathname to the executable to be used to run pip for a specific version of Python installed in the system. For example pip-3.3, if there are both Python 2.7 and 3.3 installations in the system and you want to run pip for the Python 3.3 installation. It cannot be specified together with the 'virtualenv' parameter (added in 2.1). By default, it will take the appropriate version for the python interpreter use by ansible, e.g. pip3 on python 3, and pip2 or pip on python 2.

*Update:*

To combine `virtualenv` path and alternative executable, use `virtualenv_command` like this:

```
- pip:
    virtualenv: /tmp/py3
    virtualenv_command: /usr/bin/python3 -m venv
    name: boto
```

Absolute path is required for `virtualenv_command`.

Comment: I changed the above line to: `pip: 
executable=pip3 virtualenv={{ virtualenv_path }} requirements={{ virtualenv_path }}/requirements.txt`
Error says: parameters are mutually exclusive: ['executable', 'virtualenv']

Comment: And when I remove virtualenv parameter it throws some other error.

Comment: @kamayani It would be very helpful to hear how you resolved it.  I'm still having this problem.

Answer (score 20):

Had the same issue. There is workaround with usage `executable`:

```
- name: Install and upgrade pip
  pip:
    name: pip
    extra_args: --upgrade
    executable: pip3
```